# Adicionar vídeo no Moodle

Tags: php, moodle

Estou tentando saber como eu adiciono meu vídeo no Moodle, utilizando o diretório SRC.

Tenho meu próprio tema, e nele conterá um box fixo com um vídeo. Gostaria de implementar esse vídeo no meu código HTML5 normal com a tag `video`.

Estou me perdendo no diretório. 
Alguém sabe como é?

Answer (score 2):

O Moodle 2.6 possui uma função do objeto $OUTPUT chamada pix_url que recebe o nome da imagem, contudo ela não funcionaria para o vídeo, uma outra opção seria usar algumas variaveis e funções do moodle para obter o caminho para a pasta do tema onde provavelmente está seu vídeo algo como

```
<?php echo $CFG->wwwroot.'/theme/'.current_theme() ?>
```

Fazendo isso você terá uma URL que direciona para a pasta do seu tema, ai é adicionar /caminhodovideo/

Olhando o código interno do moodle ele mesmo se segura nesta variável para muitas de suas bibliotecas como o próprio /lib/outputrenderers.php e o /lib/pagelib.php, então é bem segura de ser usada.